# Accessing dynamic keys from a json object of an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I need to access keys of a json object which was created dynamically . The array structure is:

```
self.arrayObj : Array[2]
  >0:Object
   >Display1
    ->InnerObjects
   >__proto
  >1:Object
   >Display2
    -->InnerObjects
```

Key is "Display1" and value is object. This key is dynamic and not fixed . How can I access the Key string from array above.

The output I am expecting as : "Display1" and "Display2"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
var keys = [];//final output of all key names

arrayObj.forEach(function(val){
  keys.concat(Object.keys(val));
});
```

`keys` now has all the dynamic property names.

Answer (score 1):

Using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) you can do:

```js
var arrayObj = [{'Display1': {'InnerObjects': {}}}, {'Display2': {'InnerObjects': {}}}];

var result = arrayObj.map(function(val, index) {
  return Object.keys(val)[0];
});

document.write('arrayObj keys: ' + result.toString());
```